# Where is this app located?

Tags: applications

I have an old version of Sublime Text which I installed manually, and recently added a PPA and installed a new one. Now I have two icons in Planck:

[image]

old one to the left, new one to the right.

I want to know where the old one is located to remove it, but I can't. I've tried several commands but they all point to the new one. I have not found the icon that corresponds to the old one either.

How can I find where this app is located in my disk?

**Edit**

After restarting the system, things changed a little bit. Now there are no two icons in Plank, only in the app launcher:

[image]

and both open the same (new) version of Sublime. So now I don't know where this second launcher is, and I also can not launch the old version anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel,

Any customization to the Plank is done at the user account level. So, we could attempt to find your data this way:
1. Go to *Applications -> Terminal* (or Win+T)
2. Type: `cd ~`
3. Type: `cd .config/plank/dock1/launchers`
4. Type: `ls -lt`
**NOTE:** This will list all of the files, newest first.
5. Type: `cat sublime_text.dockitem | grep Launcher`
**NOTE:** The path to the executable will be displayed (e.g. .../usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop)
6. From step #4 you *should* see a second variation on the name sublime_text.dockitem.  Please repeat step #5 with the name of the second dockitem for the path to the second Sublime text application.
7. After you have the path, the removal of the application can be accomplished with the usual procedures.
8. When you are finished with Terminal you can exit with `Cont+D`.

I hope that helps.  Good luck!

**UPDATE:** Gabriel, from our experiments with the Plank (and Sublime text) we know the name of the executable for Sublime. So, if you return to the Terminal (or Win+T) and type: `sudo find / -type f -name sublime_text` (all on one line) that should do the job! That command uses sudo for full access and will only locate file names with the exact name "sublime_text".
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks K, but after restarting the system things changed. Please see the updated question. Also, there is only one `sublime*.dockitem` file in that folder.

Comment: Gabriel, if you open the Terminal (Win+T) and type: `cd $HOME/.local/share/applications` followed by `ls -al` you may see the "extra" Sublime Text.  Good luck.

Comment: Nope. Only Chrome apps, the Dropbox app, and a `mimeapps.list` file. Nothing else.

Comment: Gabriel, from our experiments with the Plank (and Sublime text) we know the name of the executable for Sublime.  So, if you return to the Terminal (Win+T) and type: `sudo find / -type f -name sublime_text` (all on one line) that should do the job!  That command uses sudo for full access and will only locate file names with the exact name "sublime_text".  Good luck.

Comment: That did the trick! I see three folders under `/snap/`: `sublime-text/38/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text`, `sublime-text/44/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text`, `sublime-text/51/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text`. The first two executables are the old version, the one in the `51` folder is the new one. Not sure what those old versions are doing there, but at least now I know where they are. Would you like to add this to your answer? Thank you!

Comment: This is related to the `snap` package storing older versions apparently. I wasn't even aware I was using `snap` to install apps.

Comment: Gabriel, I'm glad it worked.  Although I have used AppCenter, CLI: apt install, GDebi and Flatpak -- I have **not** used snap for installing apps under Elementary OS.  I'm glad our search resulted the information you required to resolve this question.